# Html body background image doesn't work in ios 5

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad, background

This code works in ios 6 but not in ios 5. Any idea?

```
NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bg10.jpg"];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];

NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"<html><body background=\"%@\"></body></html>",url];

[self.WebView setOpaque:NO];
self.WebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[WebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

Comment: try `@"<html><body background=bg10.jpg"></body></html>"`

Answer (score 0):

The body `background` attribute is not supported in `HTML5`. You should instead tweak that and use CSS, to guarantee it be portable with different iOS versions.

This should do the trick:

```
NSString *htmlString = 
 [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: 
    @"<html><body style=\"background-image:url(%@)\"></body></html>",url];
```

Comment: What happens if you set the background to a color... does it show anything in either environment?

Answer (score 0):

you can do one thing.
put the `imageview` behind the `webview` and make `webview` transparent:

```
WebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
WebView.opaque = NO;
```

I think you can also make those changes in Interface Builder in the UIWebViews properties.

Now Set the imageview with your image. It will work as a background for `webview` cause it is now transparent.